# How to create a folder and rename the file name of a downloaded file in spreadsheet using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm a student and im really new to the google apps environment specifically google scripts. So here's my problem, i'm trying to download a file from an external link and save it to google drive. But the file is being saved in my default folder of my google drive. All i want is to automatically creates a folder(if does not exist) and rename the file name automatically.
Comments will be highly appreciated.

```
 function downloadFile(){
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var url = sh.getRange('B1').getValue();
    var user = "testestest";
    var password = "testtesttest";
    var headers = {
            "Accept": "application/xml",
            "Content-Type": "application/xml",
            "Authorization": "Basic "+ Utilities.base64Encode(user+":"+password)
    };

      var options = {
            "method" : "get",
            "headers" : headers 
      };

      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options).getBlob();
      var file = DriveApp.createFile(response);
      Logger.log(file);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a portion of code I wrote to create a folder if it doesn't exist :

```
var inFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(sheetId).getParents().next().getId();
// this line gets the sheet (the document I am working on), then gets its parent folder and stores its ID.

  // Logger.log("inFolder : " + inFolder);
var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(inFolder).getFolders();
// we now retrieve all folders in the previously located folder
while(folders.hasNext()){
// we now cycle through all the found folders
var folder = folders.next();
// we get the next folder
var folderName = folder.getName();
// we get its name
if(folderName == "Retenues"){
  var retenuesFolderId = folder.getId();
// if there is a folder with the name, it means that this folder exists.
  var folderExists = true;
  // Logger.log("Le dossier existe déjà."); 
 } 
}

if(folderExists != true){
var retenuesFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderById(inFolder).createFolder("Retenues").getId();
```

}

EDIT : I've added some comments in the above code.

Explanation :

The script first locates where my spreadsheet is in my Drive. It then will list all existing folders in the folder where the sheet is. It will check if there is an already existing folder with a particular name. If not, it will create it and then put the file in it.

In your case, you could just download the file you want, it will automatically get an ID. Get this ID, and copy (I am not sure if you can move files, I think you have to copy them) it to the folder.

Comment: Hi i have another question to ask. So here's the thing i need to create a file in an existing folder how can i do that? can you help me with it?
I trying using same method but always gets this error
"TypeError: Cannot find function getFiles in object FolderIterator."

Comment: The folder iterator (getFolders) only gets folders, not files. If you want to get a specific file in a specific folder, you have to get the folder first and then get the file. Hence the ID you must store somewhere, both for the folder and the file.